# Performing Many-to-Many query filter | MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

So, I have 4 tables:

- Drugs
- Manufacturers
- Drug_manufacturers
- drug_reports

Drugs table

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | row 1 |
| 2 | row 2 |

Manufacturers table:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ДИГОКСИН ТАБЛ. 0,25МГ №40 |
| 2 | DRUG NAME 54 |

Drug manufacturers table

| drug_id | manufacturer_id | counter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 1 | 45 | 2 |

And drug_reports table

| id | period_code | drug_id | manufacturer_id | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A100 | 1 | 3 | 01.01.2023 |
| 2 | A101 | 1 | 45 | 01.01.2023 |
| 3 | A102 | 2 | 3 | 01.01.2023 |

So i created as following query:

```
SELECT dr.id, dm.counter, dr.period_code, dr.drug_id, d.name, m.name FROM drug_reports dr
LEFT JOIN drugs d ON dr.drug_id = d.id
LEFT JOIN drug_manufacturers dm ON d.id = dm.drug_id
LEFT JOIN manufacturers m ON dm.manufacturer_id = m.id
WHERE dr.period_code LIKE '%72411 IM%'
```

It returnes:

[image: result screenshot]

Interestingly, id: 412790 and period_code: *72411 IM* information is one record in table. As a result, it was returned several times. Too much data is being returned multiple times.
I also tried as following query, but it also returned incorrect data:

```
SELECT dr.id, dm.counter, dr.period_code, dr.drug_id, d.name, m.name FROM drug_reports dr
LEFT JOIN drugs d ON dr.drug_id = d.id
LEFT JOIN drug_manufacturers dm ON d.id = dm.drug_id
LEFT JOIN manufacturers m ON dm.manufacturer_id = m.id AND dr.mf_id = dm.manufacturer_id
WHERE dr.period_code LIKE '%72411 IM%'
```

I need as following result:

| dr.id | peroid_code | name | counter | Manufacturer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 412790 | 72411 IM | ДИГОКСИН ТАБЛ. 0,25МГ №40 | 5 | ARPIMED |

How to write a proper query? Can anyone has idea?

Comment: Can you make your sample data and expected output consistent between each other?

Comment: In my table has Russian data and many rows, columns. I tried to make my question easy to read.

Comment: You want to structure this as a GROUP BY query. Build it up one table at a time.

Comment: Apart from russian text, "412790", "72411 IM", "ARPIMED" are never present in your sample data, where do they come from?

Comment: Another option, is to create an expected output table wrt the current sample input tables you've shared.

Answer (score 0):

The following query I made shows all the data in the linked table in the middle during a many-to-many join. That is

```
SELECT dr.id, dm.counter, dr.period_code, dr.drug_id, d.name, m.name FROM drug_reports dr
LEFT JOIN drugs d ON dr.drug_id = d.id
LEFT JOIN drug_manufacturers dm ON d.id = dm.drug_id
LEFT JOIN manufacturers m ON dm.manufacturer_id = m.id
WHERE dr.period_code LIKE '%72411 IM%'
```

So, I wrote following query:

```
SELECT 
 dr.id,
 (SELECT dm.counter FROM drug_manufacturers dm WHERE dm.drug_id = dr.drug_id AND dm.manufacturer_id = dr.mf_id LIMIT 1 ) as COUNTER
 dr.period_code,
 dr.drug_id,
 d.name,
 m.name 
FROM drug_reports dr
LEFT JOIN drugs d ON dr.drug_id = d.id
LEFT JOIN manufacturers m ON dm.manufacturer_id = m.id
WHERE dr.period_code LIKE '%72411 IM%'
```

It returned what i want result. And no any dublicate records in result.
Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Since there are multiple "names" for each drug, but you want only one name for each, the query is incorrectly structured.  Here are ways to fix that:

**Plan A:**

```
SELECT ... MIN(m.name) AS name1
    FROM ... LEFT JOIN ...
    GROUP BY dr.id
```

The `MIN` or `MAX` or `ANY_VALUE`, together with the `GROUP BY`, collapses multiple possible values into one.

**Plan B:**

```
SELECT ... 
       GROUP_CONCAT(m.name) AS alt_names
    FROM ... LEFT JOIN ...
    GROUP BY dr.id
```

This is similar to Plan A, but strings out the alternate names in a commalist.

**Plan C:**

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ( SELECT ... FROM drug_reports WHERE period_code LIKE '%72411 IM%' ) AS dr
    LEFT JOIN ...
```

This *starts* by picking only the one relevant row from `drug_reports`, *then* looks up the other info.  If the tables are huge, Plan C is likely to be the fastest.